# Trotec TTK 50 E ugly noise from relay

Tags: repair

I have a Trotek TTK 50 E dehumidifier ( https://uk.trotec.com/fileadmin/downloads/Entfeuchtung/TTK50E/TRT-BA-TTK50E-TC-002-EN.pdf ). Recently it stopped working. Ugly noises came from it.

I disassembled it a bit and it turned out that the compressor is working, but the fan is not starting up, and the ugly noise coming from one (or two) relays.

The relays are on a small panel along with IC, transistors, capacitors etc.

I can solder things, and I have a multimeter too, but otherwise I am beginner in repairing things like this.

Is it worth to try to replace the relays or capacitors? If yes, what should be the first suspect, relay or capacitors, or something else?

The noise is coming from the black boxes.

I disconnected the orange (fan) wire from the panel.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One cause for the problem might be a faulty capacitor. The one that is bulging.

Comment: Thank you for noticing on the photo what I have not noticed with my own eyes! I will start with replacing the swelled capacitor.

Comment: How did you manage to disassemble the plastic case? I can't take out the screws at the top behind the handle. TTK 50S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the bulging (and for safety s sake the other too) capacitor and the relay (s) stopped making noises, and 230V appeared on the "cmp" and "fan" pins. The compressor started up, but the fan not. I measured infinite resistance on the fan motor. I disassembled the fan motor a bit and it turned out that a thermal fuse was glued to the winding and it was broken. After fixing that everything started up.

I guess that after the capacitor broke down, the fan stopped working but the compressor not, overheating the motor and breaking the thermal fuse.

Anyway it's working fine again!

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"I guess that after the capacitor broke down, the fan stopped working but the compressor not, overheating the motor and breaking the thermal fuse."_ Most excellent conclusion!